# Is it possible to monitor cellular network data transfer on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

Is it possible to monitor cellular network data transfer on the iPhone programmatically? If yes how?

Or it not possible because 3party application can not run on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible on a non-jailbroken phone. Probably possible if you jailbreak.

Comment: thanks Ben, the reason is 3party application can not run on background right?

Comment: The reason is twofold—third-party applications cannot run in the background, yes, but the iPhone SDK also just doesn't allow you that low-level a source of information about the device.